# rpcinfo -p shows different output depending on client?

Tags: nfs, port

I'm troubleshooting an NFS issue, and found something unexpected: rpcinfo reports different output depending on what client I run it from. What would cause this? (inherited server; no idea if it was purposely configured this way, or how)

This is the (correct, expected) output I get on a random machine that does not need to mount the NFS share:

```
me@random_client:~$ rpcinfo -p nfs_server.example.com
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  35726  status
    100024    1   tcp  55115  status
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   tcp   2049
    100227    3   tcp   2049
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   udp   2049
    100227    3   udp   2049
    100021    1   udp  46086  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  46086  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  46086  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  47752  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  47752  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  47752  nlockmgr
    100005    1   udp  36001  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  36810  mountd
    100005    2   udp  44952  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  37364  mountd
    100005    3   udp  42206  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  49171  mountd
```

This is the (incorrect, unexpected) output I get on the machine that *does* need to mount the NFS share.

```
me@desired_client:~$ rpcinfo -p nfs_server.example.com
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  52768  status
    100024    1   tcp  60092  status
    100021    1   udp  35877  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  35877  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  35877  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  39358  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  39358  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  39358  nlockmgr
```

What gives? Why am I not seeing NFS?

---

Update: `showmount` results

correct, expected output from random machine that does not need to mount the NFS share:

```
me@random_client:~$ showmount -e nfs_server.example.com
Export list for nfs_server.example.com:
/mnt/sharedrive desired_client,otherclient1,otherclient2
```

incorrect, unexpected output from the machine that *does* need to mount the NFS share:

```
me@desired_client:~$ showmount -e nfs_server.example.com
clnt_create: RPC: Program not registered
```

Google suggests that `RPC: Program not registered` indicates the NFS server isn't running, but clearly that's not happening here since the other machine can see it just fine?

Comment: rpc services nfs and mountd are for an NFS server. On each client run `showmount -e <server>` for more info. I have an nfs client that has the same rpc services and versions as desired_client and it can mount nfs exports.

Comment: Compelling idea, but alas, showmount is borked from the nonworking client. Must be something else.

Comment: Does `showmount -e` from a working client lead you to believe desired_client could mount the export? Does `rpcinfo -p <server>` from desired_client  show anything? Are there firewalls on server, client, or in-between? Does setting the kernel debug flags via `rpcdebug` on server or client show anything? What does a network packet capture on both ends show? Is selinux enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Ahahahahahaha, this was an own goal.

```
me@desired_client:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       nfs_server.example.com
[...]
```

The offending loopback entry was apparently added by IT after `desired_client` went bonkers a few weeks ago when `nfs_server` went down for repairs unexpectedly. They didn't mention they'd fixed it by modifying `hosts`...

(sometimes brute force works -- i figured it out by going through `/etc` in reverse chronological order)